# Plot points playing games when I try to size by a value count in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, bokeh

I'm trying to get the plot points in a scatter graph to size according to the frequency of values in a column of data. The data is coming from a questionnaire.

**My questions are**: What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

I can push out a simple plot with x and y values coming from 2 columns of data. The X axis represents a level (1-100), and the Y axis represents a choice users can make for each level (1-4). For this plot I want to track how many people choose 1-4 on each level - so I need to capture that 1-4 has been selected, then indicate how many times.

[Simple plot works fine, though those points have multiple occurrences.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQMqH.png)

Here's the code for that:

```
# Set up the graph
WT_Number = data.wt        # This is the X axis
CFG_Number = data.cfg      # This is the Y axis

wt_cfg_plot = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=400,
                 title="Control Form Groups chosen by WT unit")

# Set up the plot points, including the Hover Tool
cr = wt_cfg_plot.scatter(WT_Number, CFG_Number, size=7, 
               fill_color="blue",
               line_color=None, alpha=0.7, hover_fill_color="firebrick",
               hover_line_color=None, hover_alpha=1)
```

**Problem**: I then added a value count and set it as the size, to get the plot points to adjust according to the value frequency. But now it pumps out this chart and throws an error:

[Plot points are reacting to the code, but now they're doing their own thing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bXMZ.png)

I added a variable for the value counts (cfg_freq), and used that as the size:

```
cfg_freq = data['cfg'].value_counts()*4

cr = wt_cfg_plot.scatter(WT_Number, CFG_Number, size=cfg_freq, fill_color="blue",
               line_color=None, alpha=0.7, hover_fill_color="firebrick",
               hover_line_color=None, hover_alpha=1)
```

Here's the the last part of the error being thrown:

> File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/core/properties.py", line 722, in **setattr**
>       (name, self.**class**.**name**, text, nice_join(matches)))
>
> AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'size' to Chart, possible attributes are above, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_fill_alpha, border_fill_color, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, h_symmetry, height, hidpi, left, legend, lod_factor, lod_interval, lod_threshold, lod_timeout, logo, min_border, min_border_bottom, min_border_left, min_border_right, min_border_top, name, outline_line_alpha, outline_line_cap, outline_line_color, outline_line_dash, outline_line_dash_offset, outline_line_join, outline_line_width, plot_height, plot_width, renderers, responsive, right, tags, title, title_standoff, title_text_align, title_text_alpha, title_text_baseline, title_text_color, title_text_font, title_text_font_size, title_text_font_style, tool_events, toolbar_location, tools, v_symmetry, webgl, width, x_mapper_type, x_range, xgrid, xlabel, xscale, y_mapper_type, y_range, ygrid, ylabel or yscale

Comment: It's certainly good of you to try including all relevant information, but this is a very long question. While you wait for an answer, you might want to see if you can reproduce the error with a simpler code snippet. If you can do so, and thereby reduce the length of your question, I think it'll make it easier for people to answer you.

Comment: Thanks David, much appreciated. I've edited it down a bit. Still a little long, but hopefully more comprehensible.

Comment: That should help. I don't know about bokeh so I can't really help you out, unfortunately.

Comment: This is **really** weird. `Figure` does not inherit from `Chart` so I don't see how that particular exception `"unexpected attribute 'size' to Chart"` could possibly happen. I'd really encourage you to come by the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) to discuss this with us. If you can share a complete script to reproduce this that would really help. In the mean time, can you try using the `circle` glyph method instead, i.e. use `wt_cfg_plot.circle` instead of `wt_cfg_plot.scatter` ?

Comment: Hi BRD, I will try the circle glyph and see how that goes.  I'll also head over to the discussion and share the full code. You're help is greatly appreciated.